# Difference in usage of "regular", "usual", "ordinary", "normal", "common"

Tags: differences, adjectives

Sometimes it is obvious which of the following words to use, sometimes not:

- *regular*
- *usual*
- *ordinary*
- *normal*
- *common*

For example: "regular coffee" (not *usual*, *normal* or *ordinary*) , "ordinary people" (not *regular*), "usual way to do something" (sometimes "common way").

Please help me understand the difference between these words.

Comment: Interesting note: I would use "regular water" to distinguish it from "sparkling water", but on a recent vacation to Cuba they consistently used "natural water".

Comment: And some restaurants use the term "still water." Sometimes I will say "tap water" just to see if it makes them squirm.

Comment: @mfe yuck, still water makes me think of insects breeding in still/stagnant water

Comment: @NickAldwin I might be in favor of no one having to order that.

Comment: @mfe: I would not use *tap water*. In many places tap water is not clean enough to drink, so *sill water* would be better (as in bottled water than comes from a clean source).

Answer (score 11):

To be perfectly honest, each of these are interchangeable for the most part (given the details explained), and I would guess that certain phrases only sound 'off' because of a lack of familiarity, or, over-familiarity with other constructions: they all indicate a sense of typical circumstance, commonplace.

If we look at the origins as far back as required then we can see quite clearly how we've carried each through:

> **[Regular](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/regular)**:
>
> - from Late Latin *regularis*, according to rule,
> - from Latin *regula*, rod, rule;
>
> **[Usual](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/usual)**:
>
> - from Latin *usus*, *use*, from past participle of *uti*, to use.
>
> **[Ordinary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ordinary)**:
>
> - from Latin *ordinarius*,
> - from ordo, *ordin-*, *order*;
>
> **[Normal](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/normal)**:
>
> - from Late Latin *normalis*,
> - from Latin, made according to the square, from *norma*, carpenter's square;
>
> **[Common](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=common)**:
>
> - from Latin *communitatem* "community, fellowship,"
> - from *communis*, "common, public, general, shared by all or many,"

*'according to rule'*, *'order'*, *'carpenter's square'* and *'fellowship / shared by all or many'* are all synonymous in trying to say that things are as they should be - any other state is *different* and, back then, undesirable, and potentially *unusable* (see: *'to use'* above.)

So, each of these refer to a state of normality that today all are equally acceptable, the main difference being selfishness: they now refer mostly to one's self rather than being used in an altruistic fashion (i.e. not necessarily *'for the common good'* of society.)

That's my two-penneth, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The just to add to the confusion many of these have very specific meanings in technical usage

eg in maths:
*regular* expression
*usual* topology
*ordinary* differential equation
*normal* form
*common* factor

Comment: hehe, very interesting comparison :)

Answer (score 1):

I just saw [this answer at **Programmers SE**](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/152652/7768) which is an answer to a question about a working situation, where he asks if this is normal.

The answer I point to say that it is ***not*** normal, but it ***is*** common. This is an interesting differentiation of the two terms.

The situation is *common* in the meaning that similar cases occur many places, and many are in a similar situation.

But it is not *normal*, as this is not how it should be. It is more like a "freaky" situation (and I think we all agree that *freaky* is ***not*** normal ).