# 'Usually' Or 'Normally'

Tags: word-choice

I think use of "usually" and "normally" is similar in English usage, and both are correct and exchangeable. I prefer 'normally' in most of my writings. Is there any suggestion for me?

Comment: Though ultimately they imply nearly the same thing, *usually* relates more to time and frequency while *normally* is about the nature of circumstances.

Comment: That comment from @Kris is basically your answer, TechShali.

Comment: Things are usually abnormal.

Comment: Also, normally has a different meaning if you are in a scientific (statistic) context.

Comment: @nico: Yes, that is rather in line with my answer: Normal random variables follow the standard (or the probability law) of the Gaussian distribution. Do check out the history of the term 'normal': http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#History

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference in usage of "regular", "usual", "ordinary", "normal", "common"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23490/difference-in-usage-of-regular-usual-ordinary-normal-common)

Answer (score 4):

**Usual** comes from the Latin [usus](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=usual&allowed_in_frame=0) which means *custom*, while **normal** is from the Latin [norma](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=norm&allowed_in_frame=0)  meaning *rule* or *pattern*.

Though the two words are used interchangeably, there is an etymological difference: You use *usually* when you talk of a habit or custom and normally when there is an underlying *rule* or *order*.

Examples:

- I usually do not wake up before 10 AM. (Your personal habit)
- The school normally closes at four in the afternoon. (The rules of the school)

Answer (score 2):

"Usually" does not seem to quote the same amount of regularity. An event may usually occur, but that almost implies that the other events have and will occur in its place. On the other hand, "normally" seems to imply that unless there are extraordinary circumstances, this is what will occur.

Comment: Based on your answer here are two examples I should think before using.
Usually, I do it.
Normally, I don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

Normally (OAAD)

1 - **usually**: in normal circumstances

> I'm not normally allowed to stay out late. 
>   It's normally much warmer than this in July. 
>   It normally takes 20 minutes to get there.

2 - in the usual or ordinary way

> Her heart is beating normally.
>   Just try to behave normally.

Usually (OAAD)

in the way that is usual or normal; most often

> I'm usually home by 6 o'clock.
> We usually go by car.
> How long does
>   the trip usually take?